# Can the Flash Player ActiveX on Windows Embedded Compact 7 (V10.1.62.47) be used out of the browser?

Tags: flash, compact-framework, windows-embedded-compact

I'm having problems hosting the Flash ActiveX in a .net compact framework forms application on Windows Embedded Compact 7. I have used the AxHost implementation from this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446515.aspx - but the activeX won't play movies. I have had it working on an earlier version of Windows Mobile with Flash for Pocket PC but when using the AxShockwaveFlash control in WEC7 the movie just doesn't play. I just see a grey control. I don't believe the ActiveX is loading properly, as the OnReadyStateChaged event doesn't go through state 3 as it does on the PocketPC version before reaching state 4. Also, I can change the BGColor property all I want but the control only ever appears grey. Has anyone every actually got this version of the Flash ActiveX to work in any other container other than a browser?

Regards,

Chris Chambers.